# Javascript converting an array to a string and making it output in reverse

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, reverse

When I write the code below everything is reversed on output as expected.

```
var sequence = "kick snare hat openHat";
var sequenceBackwards = sequence.split('').reverse().join('');
document.write(sequenceBackwards);
```

However when I have an Array, then convert it to a string then do the same proceedure it doesn't work.

```
var sequence = ["kick","snare", "hat","openHat"];
sequence.toString();
var sequenceBackwards = sequence.split('').reverse().join('');
document.write(sequenceBackwards);
```

I would like to know exactly why this doesn't work, and a working alternate example.

When I do a "typeof" for sequenceBackwards it doesn't return string.It returns object which tells me it's still an array after the supposed "conversion". I'm a bit confused on this.

I am not doing this for a project I'm curious and have been picking at it for an hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line does not change `sequence` variable, it just `returns` string:

`sequence.toString();`

`["kick", "snare", "hat", "openHat"].toString()` provides `"kick,snare,hat,openHat"`. So it is not what are you looking for.

Use

```
var sequence = ["kick", "snare", "hat", "openHat"];
var sequenceBackwards = sequence.join(' ').split('').reverse().join('');
document.write(sequenceBackwards);
```

Answer (score 1):

Array has `.reverse` method.

```
var sequence = ["kick","snare", "hat","openHat"];
sequence.reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're experiencing different behavior is because the `toString` call is joining each element together by a comma rather than a space. This code:

```
var sequence = ["kick","snare", "hat","openHat"];
sequence.toString();
```

Returns the following:

> kick,snare,hat,openHat

You can use this instead:

```
sequence.join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

This does nothing to `sequence` variable:

```
var sequence = ["kick","snare", "hat","openHat"];
sequence.toString();
```

You need to reassign it:

```
sequence = sequence.toString();
```

But `Array.toString` returns comma-separated values, but you can use `sequence.join(' ')` to concatenate values with space.